# How to change prompt colors of powerlevel9k

Tags: zsh, powerline

I installed and applied powerlevel9k to my terminal but as below, the colors of triangles are not the same as that of prompt (username, directory and branch status).

Could you tell me how to change and match those colors ?

And also if you could, please tell me how to adjust triangles in order to fit prompt perfectly.

thank you.

[my prompt](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Re8w.png)

Answer (score 1):

This depends on which Terminal Emulator you are using.
If you use the OSX `Terminal.app`, you got bad luck (see [P9K troubleshooting wiki page](https://github.com/bhilburn/powerlevel9k/wiki/Troubleshooting#segment-separators-are-wrong-color).
But this may also happen, if you use `iTerm` and did not set the minimum contrast (Profiles / Colors) to zero.

There even may be similar functionalities in other Terminal Emulators as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I changed terminal to iTerm2 and I could solve this problem. That was really helpful.